# C can someone tell me what is going on here?

Tags: c, free, malloc

I can not figure out what the heck is happening here. What I expect is that the output should say that there is only 1 element in keys, it's saying there are 7 when I have allocated only the 0 position with 120 bytes.

```
void add2(char **b, char *i) {
    if (!i) {
        b[0] = (char*) malloc(120);
        sprintf(b[0], "%s", "hithere");
    } else {
        strcat(b[0], "\\\\");
        strcat(b[0], i);
    }
}

void add1(char **b) {
    add2(b, NULL);
    add2(b, "one");
    add2(b, "two");
    add2(b, "three");
}

void add() {
    char *keys[2];
    int i;
    add1(keys);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", keys[0]);
    for (i = 0; keys[i]; i++)
        fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", i);
    free(keys[0]);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{   
     add();
     add();
     return 255;
}
```

outputs:
hithere\one\two\three
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
hithere\one\two\three
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

the strings are as I expect them to be however i thought only 0 should be printed out after since 0 is the only element I added to. I need to be able to free each spot instead of just free[0] but when i put the free[i] in the for loop that prints out i it stack dumps.

with regard to initialization from response below, if i need an array that is like 1000 instead of 2 then how do i init them all to 0 without typing out 1,000 0's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/* ... */
void add() {
    char *keys[2];
/* ... */
```

keys is an array of 2 pointers to char, but **it is not initialized**.
Try this

```
/* ... */
void add() {
    char *keys[2] = {0, 0}; /* explicit initialization of the two elements */
/* ... */
```

In the absence of explicit initializers for all members, the *uninitialized* ones are initialized to zero (the right zero for their type).

```
/* ... */
void add() {
    char *keys[1000] = {42}; /* explicit initialize the first element to 42 */
                             /* and implicitly initialize all other elements to 0 */
                             /* **ATTENTION** */
                             /* initializing a pointer to 42 is wrong */
                             /* I only wrote that as an example */
/* ... */
```

---

**Edit**, quote from the Standard

> 6.7.8 Initialization
>     Syntax
>   1
>
> > initializer:
> >
> > > assignment-expression
> > >       { initializer-list }
> > >       { initializer-list , }
> >
> > initializer-list:
> >
> > > designation<sub>opt</sub> initializer
> > >       initializer-list , designation<sub>opt</sub> initializer

There is no syntax for an empty initializer-list.

Comment: Okay so lets say I don't know how many elements I need? would I do char **keys; and then use malloc?

Comment: whats difference between that and memset(keys, '\0', sizeof(keys))?

Comment: You could just use "char *keys[SIZE] = {};" to get around typing a 5-line comment

Comment: My compiler tells me "warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces". I tried to get the proper reference out of the Standard, but didn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initialized the keys array, so it contains whatever happened to be in memory. keys[1] and on up to 7 weren't zero in that instance.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of question,

If you need to initialize an array that is like 1000 instead of 2 then use the following

```
char *keys[1000] = {0};
```

If you initialize one element of array with a value, then all other members of array will be automatically initialized to zero.

i.e., if you use

```
char *keys[1000] = {42};
```

then first member of array will be initialized to 42 and all other members of array will be automatically initialized to zero.

Comment: what about memset(keys, '\0', sizeof(keys))? is there any difference?

Comment: There is a difference if it's an array of `float`, for example. Using `{}` will initialize to `0` (or `0.0`, or null pointer value), which isn't always the same as all bits 0.

Comment: Also, you don't have to write `={0}`. You can just write `={}`.

Answer (score 1):

> *What's the difference between
>   implicitly initializing array elements
>   to 0 and explicitly setting them to 0
>   with memset()?*

```
char *data[1000] = {0};
memset(data, 0, sizeof data);
```

The first option (implicit initialization) sets every element of the array to zero of the proper type; the second option sets all bits of all elements (plus any padding) to 0. Usually (<s>99.99% of all current computers</s>) there is no difference between a **typed 0** and **all bits 0**.

Imagine a computer with segmented memory ... where a pointer is composed of two parts. When you set it to 0 (the right type of 0) the compiler can make that 0 different than all bits 0. If you specifically set all bits to 0, you might end up with an invalid pointer.

```
void *test = 0; /* can make test something like "0xC0DE:0x0000" */
memset(test, 0, sizeof test); /* will make test as "0x0000:0x0000" */
```

Comment: They say that 99% of statistics are made up on the spot.  ;)

Comment: For all integral types (including `char`), ISO C and C++ actually guarantee that "all bits 0" is the value 0 (though converse is not true: value 0 needs not be "all bits 0" - in case of sign-bit representation, which is legal, either one of +0 and -0 will have one bit not zero). So make it 100%.